# How can I publish a development version of SBT to my Artifactory ivy2 repository?

Tags: sbt

I have a development version of SBT building and publishing locally with `sbt publishLocal`, having followed the instructions on the GitHub Contributing guide.

How can I get this version of SBT publishing to my ivy2 repository hosted on an Artifactory server of my own?

I’m already able to publish other projects to this Artifactory server, I just need to know what to do to get SBT itself publishing so I can use it from other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to undo or modify some of the build definitions in sbt.
I would probably fork sbt-houserules and remove BintraySettingPlugin (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-houserules/blob/v0.3.9/src/main/scala/sbt/houserules/BintraySettingPlugin.scala), and substitute it with a `publishTo` setting.